# How do I create a pattern overlay in CSS

Tags: html, css, design-patterns, header, overlay

I'm trying to create a header for my website but I'm having a bit of difficulty as I'm new to HTML and CSS. I want to create a banner with the same font and background as shown below. They consist of a certain colour with a pattern overlay at 44% opacity, which I'm not sure how to do.

I originally uploaded the header as an image, but I was told it's bad to use large images on websites as it make it longer to load. So I tried creating it via code. If anybody could please help replicate the header below, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

[Link to my current HTML & CSS Code via Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/appyk4uk/1/)

[Link to Banner I want to replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf4Qh.png)

Comment: what's the font used in your image?

Comment: Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have your fiddle updated: [**FIDDLE**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/appyk4uk/3/)

I've fixed a few things in the html like tags not closed (your headers) and now the "container" contains the banner propely.

So now you just have to add a background image with the pattern you want and (as you did) play with the opacity value of your text.

```
#container {
    background-image:url(http://zimasolutions.com/Images/pattern.png);
    repeat:repeat;
}
```

Use the repeat option for the background image so you just need a little image.

I uploaded temporally the image pattern.png I have used as an example. I took the sample for the image you linked. In a few hours I may delete that image.

Edited: IF you want the pattern image OVER the text insteed of under it may be more complicated. You could absolute position a container over the banner but in this case you may need to change the image opacity with an image editor (like photoshop).

Comment: That's brilliant! Thanks.

I had to change a bit because that was just the header though. This is the entire website:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/appyk4uk/8/

The footer still needs work, but I haven't figured out how to do that yet. I wanted to start from the top.

I also would like to replicate the pattern onto the text. What benefit does the "Repeated pattern" do in comparison to simply uploading the entire banner? Thanks.

Comment: If it's a pattern image with repeat option... you may need just a very small image. much faster page loading time. The example I used is around 100x100 px which is like 17k size. But just got the sample real fast. probably an image around 40x40 may work exactly the same.

Comment: And if you think this is a correct answer... I would apreciated the "click" :) ty